# How to filter data.frame by a factor that includes NA as level

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

If you have a `data.frame` with factors that do not include `NA`s as levels you can filter your data without issues.

```
set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(a = factor(as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, NA,3,NA)),exclude=NULL),
           b= runif(8))
#str(df)
df[df$a==3,]
#      a         b
#    5 3 0.9404673
#    7 3 0.5281055
```

The issues appears if you need to filter by the NA level. The following does not work:

```
df[df$a==NA,]
df[df$a=="NA",]
df[is.na(df$a),]
```

The only way I found is converting the factor to numeric and compare it to the number of levels.

```
df[as.numeric(df$a)==4,]
#     a         b
#6 <NA> 0.0455565
#8 <NA> 0.8924190
```

Is there any other more intuitive/elegant way to get the same result?

Comment: Well, `df[df$a == factor(NA, levels=levels(df$a), exclude = NULL), ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the levels of the corresponding `df$a` is na:

```
df[is.na(levels(df$a)[df$a]),]
     a         b
6 <NA> 0.1649003
8 <NA> 0.6556045
```

As Frank pointed out, this also includes observations where the value of `df$a`, not just it's level, is `NA`.  I guess the original poster wanted to include these cases.  If not, one can do something like

```
x <- factor(c("A","B", NA), levels=c("A", NA), exclude = NULL)
i <- which(is.na(levels(x)[x]))
i[!is.na(x[i])]
```

gives you `3`, only the `NA`-level, leaving out unknown level (B).

Comment: I upvoted this, but then realized it still returns the wrong result for `x = factor(c("A","B", NA), levels=c("A", NA), exclude = NULL)` -- should only get the third element, but `is.na(levels(x)[x])` also picks up the second.

Comment: You are right.  ` as.integer(x)` will give `[1]  1 NA  2` and obviously `levels(x)[NA]` is `NA` as well.  Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

In case you also have true missing values (that don't belong to  the factor's levels)...

```
DF = data.frame(
  x = factor(c("A", "B", NA), levels=c("A", NA), exclude=NULL),
  v = 1:3
)
```

Row 3's `x` has level `NA`, while row 2 is a true missing value.

To get just row 3, you could do a join with data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

merge(DF, data.table(x = factor(NA_character_, exclude=NULL)))
# or
DF[.(factor(NA_character_, exclude=NULL)), on=.(x), nomatch=0]    

#     x v
# 1: NA 3
```

Or somewhat more awkwardly in dplyr:

```
dplyr::right_join(DF, 
  data.frame(x = factor(NA_character_, levels=levels(DF$x), exclude=NULL)))

# Joining, by = "x"
#      x v
# 1 <NA> 3
```

I could find no way to get here in base, except the crazy...

```
wv = which(is.na(levels(DF$x)))
DF[ !is.na(DF$x) & as.integer(DF$x) == wv, ]

#      x v
# 3 <NA> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that's a little weird that `is.na()` doesn't respond to factors.  But this seems to work:

```
set.seed(123)
df=data.frame(a = factor(as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, NA,3,NA)),exclude=NULL),
              b= runif(8))
df[is.na(as.character(df$a)),]
```

Comment: if you add `exclude=NULL` then what you have are valid values, just the level is NA

Comment: Right.  Thought about that after I wrote it :)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately SO encourages "post first, think later" behavior ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach with dplyr and the %in% operator would be:

```
df %>%
  filter(
    a %in% NA_character_
  )
#>      a         b
#> 1 <NA> 0.0455565
#> 2 <NA> 0.8924190
```

As folks here have mentioned, NA matching in R can be a little funny. The "%in% trick" provides more permissive matching, though I'm afraid I can't explain the ins-and-outs.